# java spring data jpa, hibernate, strange mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have a little trouble with stange behavior of following.
There are 3 entities: `

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Building> buildings; 

@Entity
@Table(name = "building")
public class Building {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "building", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<GeoPoint> bound;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
private Project project;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "geo_point")
public class GeoPoint {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "building_id")
private Building building;
}
```

I porposly hid unnecessary fields and methods. I have some data in db storage and when i get data with repository method findAll() I recieve proper result.

But if I use the findOne() method of repository then I get 'weird' result, 
In this case number of Building increases and equals to number of GeoPoint. ie I have many duplicates of building.

Can you explain this behavior? Might be someone had similar issue.

**edited:**

The next result was received by invoking repository.findAll() method

```js
buildings: [{id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}]
0: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
bound: [{id: 1, longitude: 47.827211, latitude: 52.0166565},…]
0: {id: 1, longitude: 47.827211, latitude: 52.0166565}
1: {id: 2, longitude: 47.8270916, latitude: 52.0167423}
2: {id: 3, longitude: 47.8272374, latitude: 52.0168192}
3: {id: 4, longitude: 47.827502, latitude: 52.0169586}
4: {id: 5, longitude: 47.8277507, latitude: 52.0170896}
5: {id: 6, longitude: 47.8280161, latitude: 52.0172294}
6: {id: 7, longitude: 47.8282689, latitude: 52.0173626}
7: {id: 8, longitude: 47.8284111, latitude: 52.0174375}
8: {id: 9, longitude: 47.8285305, latitude: 52.0173517}
9: {id: 10, longitude: 47.827211, latitude: 52.0166565}
city: null
country: null
houseNumber: "5"
id: 1
osmId: 112896787
street: "РЎС‚РµРїРЅР°СЏ СѓР»РёС†Р°"
description: "description"
id: 1
latitude: 52.02038830745109
longitude: 47.826576232910156
name: "name"
```

and invoking repository.findOne(id) method:

```js
buildings: [{id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…},…]
0: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
bound: [{id: 1, longitude: 47.827211, latitude: 52.0166565},…]
city: null
country: null
houseNumber: "5"
id: 1
osmId: 112896787
street: "РЎС‚РµРїРЅР°СЏ СѓР»РёС†Р°"
1: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
bound: [{id: 1, longitude: 47.827211, latitude: 52.0166565},…]
city: null
country: null
houseNumber: "5"
id: 1
osmId: 112896787
street: "РЎС‚РµРїРЅР°СЏ СѓР»РёС†Р°"
2: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
bound: [{id: 1, longitude: 47.827211, latitude: 52.0166565},…]
city: null
country: null
houseNumber: "5"
id: 1
osmId: 112896787
street: "РЎС‚РµРїРЅР°СЏ СѓР»РёС†Р°"
3: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
4: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
5: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
6: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
7: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
8: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
9: {id: 1, osmId: 112896787, city: null, country: null, houseNumber: "5",…}
description: "description"
id: 1
latitude: 52.02038830745109
longitude: 47.826576232910156
name: "name"
```

Comment: Could you include the actual calls (with relevant context) as well as expected and actual results?

Comment: Use Set instead of List, and avoid eager fetching as much as you can, especially for toMany associations.

Comment: Thanks, i know it works weel. However why do findOne and findAll methods return different result?

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, this behavior is caused by issue of fetch annotation.
If to add annotation @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT) it will work well.

[Discussion](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1718) about it